# Comparision Operators issue

Tags: python

```
a=input("Enter the first Number ")

b=input("Enter the next number ")

c=a>b

print("Is a greater than b ? ", c )
```

ISSUE is it showing the opposite output always like the when you enter a greater than b it showing flase and vice versa

Comment: Input returns strings not numbers.

Comment: *input* is taken as *string*.  But you're comparing *integer* numbers?  How it's possible  to compare then?

Comment: *"it showing the opposite output always"* - **One** test is not "always".  Test different scenarios and you will observe that "5" is indeed greater than "1", but "5" is also greater than "10", but "90" is also greater than "10", etc.

Comment: Ohhh ! I got it !! I am a beginner ! Thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you compare strings instead of floats
since when you are comparing stings python compares the lexicographic value of the strings, that way `"9"` is grater then `"12357645"`

if you convert the input to float that should fix it :)

```
a=input("Enter the first Number ")

b=input("Enter the next number ")

c=float(a)>float(b)

print("Is a greater than b ? ", c )
```